# How to aggregate my yearly population to larger intervals as base for APC analysis?

Tags: regression, time-series, generalized-linear-model, panel-data, epidemiology

In short: How can I aggregate the time series "total population" of 1-year basis, into a "total population" of 5-year basis? And is there any theory/article about such treatment?

Background:

Trying to do an Age-Period-Cohort Analysis, I have some data of:

(1) Yearly new cancer incidence cases, by age groups of 5 (0-5, 6-10, etc.);

(2) Yearly population, by age groups of 5

As I want to feed them for analysis with the CRAN apc package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/apc/apc.pdf) which requires the unit step of period and age to be the same, I am aggregating the data from yearly basis to 5-year basis. For the number of new incidence I can simply sum it up, but how should I process the total population?

I thought of averaging the population per 5 year, or just the max of each 5-year period, but I do not know if these ways are legit and I do not have any proof to support these actions....

Please help! Thank you so much!